# How to add new text into a text file nnly if sure that text doesn't already exist

Tags: java, io

I've been trying to create a class that "UPDATES", "DELETES" and "INSERTS NEW CONTENT" into a text file. The "update" and "delete" parts work right. The "Insert new content" doesn't seem to do anything". Could anyone please advice me on what I might be getting wrong or missing in my code.

I don't get any error reports nor code error highlights.

I'm trying to have new content written into the text file if such is not already in the text file. This could be similar to where a user's details are entered into a text file for storage if he\she's a new user; if already registered no new data is entered, but they can edit or delete their previously stored details.

I would really appreciate it if someone helped where they can.

Thank you in advance.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class EditDelete {

    static PrintWriter pw;
    static String line = null;

    public static void newEntry() {
        pw.println("A NEW ENTRY");
        pw.flush();
    }

  public static void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {

    try {

      File inFile = new File("/D:/TestFile.txt/");

      if (!inFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
        return;
      }

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
          pw.println(line);
          pw.flush();
        } else if (line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
          pw.println("THIS GOT CHANGED" + "\n" + "\n");
          pw.flush();
        } else if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove) && !line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
            newEntry();
        }
      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't making sense:

```
    if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
      pw.println(line);
      pw.flush();
    } else if (line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
      pw.println("THIS GOT CHANGED" + "\n" + "\n");
      pw.flush();
    } else if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove) && !line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {
        newEntry();
    }
```

Look at the conditions:

1. If it doesn't start with that ...
2. If it does start with that ... (but that's what else means)
3. There are not other possibilities so the 3rd one can't happen. (i.e. It either does or doesn't start with that.) [But looking at the code it tests for the same thing twice but it its true one time it will always be true. `a && a` is always the same as `a` alone.]

You want to do one of three things. Add another argument to the function for the action and another for the new line to add. Rename the other one since we aren't always removing it:

```
public static void removeLineFromFile(String file, int action, String lineToFind, String newLine) {
```

Then make your test like this:

```
switch (action) {
case 1:
    ... remove line
    break;
case 2:
    ... replace line with 'newLine'
    break;
case 3:
    ... add 'newLine' after the old line
    break;
default:
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal Option");
}
```

Be sure to rewrite any lines that don't match the 'lineToFind'

Comment: 'lineToRemove' is an identifier like a school ID which uniquely identifies each line. The first if is supposed to delete the ID'd line. The second Edits, the third 'Adds new content'.

Comment: "Supposed to" is the key word. It doesn't do that. It can't do that because you have a single id and it is either found or not. That's two states. You want to do three things and you can't do three things when you only allow two states.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It's a little messy and you can clean it up. But its pretty much what you are looking for. You can add an entry and if it exists, it wont add it again. It will also delete an entry just fine. Check out the main method for its usage. The constructor handles creating the file if it does not exist.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileModification
{
    private File file = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    public FileModification(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add an entry if it doesn't exist
     * 
     * @param entry
     * @return true if successfully added/updated
     */
    public boolean addEntry(String entry)
    {
        try
        {
            // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original
            // filename.
            File tempFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            // Read from the original file and write to the new
            // unless content matches data to be removed.
            String line;
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.equals(entry))
                {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    System.out.println("Is duplicate");
                }
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }

            if(!isDuplicate)
            {
                System.out.println("Added: " + entry);

                pw.println(entry);
                pw.flush();
            }

            pw.close();
            br.close();

            // Delete the original file
            if (!file.delete())
            {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return false;
            }

            // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(file))
            {
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entry
     * 
     * @param entry
     * @return true if successfully deleted
     */
    public boolean deleteEntry(String entry)
    {
        try
        {
            // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original
            // filename.
            File tempFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            // Read from the original file and write to the new
            // unless content matches data to be removed.
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line.equals(entry))
                {
                    pw.println(line);
                    pw.flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Deleted: " + entry);
                }
            }
            pw.close();
            br.close();

            // Delete the original file
            if (!file.delete())
            {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return false;
            }

            // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(file))
            {
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return the file
     */
    public File getFile()
    {
        return file;
    }

    /**
     * @param file
     *            the file to set
     */
    public void setFile(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileModification mod = new FileModification(new File("TEST.txt"));
        mod.addEntry("NEW ENTRY1");
        mod.addEntry("NEW ENTRY2");
        mod.addEntry("NEW ENTRY3");

        mod.deleteEntry("NEW ENTRY1");
    }
}
```